# How to export some functions from another package in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

There are two packages `bon` and `bon.internal`

There's `inspect` function defined in `bon.internal`.

I would like to export as if it's in the `bon` package, something like

```
package bon

export bon.internal.inspect as inspect
```

Is that possible?

Comment: If I recall you can just change the `package`declaration to what you want, it doesn't have to match the directory structure. You'll get a warning though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. You have to redefine it

```
fun inspect(arg1: Type1, ...) = bon.internal.inspect(arg1, ...)
```

or to define it as part of `bon` package in the first place.

Scala 3 (not yet released) [supports this](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/export.html), I don't think there are any plans for Kotlin.